# Combo Box Size Issue After All Items Are Removed

Tags: c#, combobox, resize, selecteditem

My application contains a ComboBox that the user can delete items from. When the program starts up it populates the ComboBox from a list of strings read in from a configuration file.

Here is the code to add items:

```
// version list is an array of strings
foreach (string version in versionList)
{
  versionComboBox.Items.Add(version);
}
if (versionComboBox.Items.Count > 0)
{
    versionComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the combo box after it's been populated:

[image: Combo Box Initial]

If the user clicks the *Delete* button the program removes the selected item from the ComboBox using the following code:

```
if (versionComboBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
    versionComboBox.Items.Remove(versionComboBox.SelectedItem);
}
if (versionComboBox.Items.Count > 0)
{
    versionComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the combo box after a few items have been removed:

[image: Combo Box Reduced]

The problem I am having is when the last item is removed the ComboBox resizes itself to the size it was when it was initially populated. There aren't any items in the ComboBox but it sizes itself as if there were.

Here is a screenshot after all the items have been removed:

[image: Combo Box Cleared]

As you can see the size is too big. I would think that after all the items were cleared it would look like the following:

[image: Combo Box Initial No Data]

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear your combo box you can add this:

```
if (versionComboBox.Items.Count == 0)
{
    versionComboBox.Text = string.Empty;
    versionComboBox.Items.Clear();
    versionComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Another approach is to manipulate the items in the data source and rebind the control each time (a lot less for you to worry about).

Comment: That worked awesome! Seems kind of strange that I have to do that but oh well at least it works. :)

Comment: Strange. I have 2 combo boxes but your solution worked for only 1 of them. I compared the properties for both combo boxes and the one difference I found was a bool property called *IntegralHeight*. The one it worked for had this property set to false and the one it didn't work for had this property set to true. So I changed the property to false for the broken one at it now works for both! Note to self... look up (sometime) what *IntegralHeight* does.

Comment: @JanTacci I just tested it with or without `IntegralHeight` with no difference. Must be something else. Hmmm

Comment: Yeah perhaps but at least it's working for me now. I might investigate it later for future reference but for now I must move on. :)

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov thanks for your answer but i set IntegralHeight to false and you solution worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use this at the end of your code when you are filling the combobox items:

```
comboBoxNumTreno.IntegralHeight = true; // auto fit dropdown list
```

Then to clear it up:

```
comboBoxNumTreno.ResetText();
comboBoxNumTreno.Items.Clear();
comboBoxNumTreno.SelectedIndex = -1;
comboBoxNumTreno.DropDownHeight = 106; // default value
comboBoxNumTreno.IntegralHeight = false;
```

Comment: This worked whereas the comment marked as the solution did not for me.  Full disclosure: I have the cleanup code in the ComboBox_DataSourceChanged event handler.

Thanks Luke!!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but it took me a long time to figure this out and I wanted to let anyone in the future know. After you clear your combo box just do a blank add items and it resets the height.

```
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
comboBox1.Items.Add("");
```

Answer (score 0):

set DropDownHeight property to fix size

```
 versionComboBox.DropDownHeight = 106; // default value
```