# ComboBox.DropDownHeight values doesn't change when adding or removing items

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

When running the following code in a WFA

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] items = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UpdateDropDownHeight();
    }

    private void UpdateDropDownHeight()
    {
        textBox1.Text = comboBox1.DropDownHeight.ToString();
    }

    private void button_populate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<items.Length; i++)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(items[i]);
        }
        UpdateDropDownHeight();
    }

    private void button_clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        UpdateDropDownHeight();
    }
}
```

I have noticed the `combobox1.DropDownHeight` value never changes when new items are added to the combo box.  The apparent drop down area clearly changes when `button_populate` is clicked through.
Another users question

> [Combo Box Size Issue After All Items Are Removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769148/combo-box-size-issue-after-all-items-are-removed)

provides a somewhat perplexing answer on how to resize the apparent drop down area after removing items. What then is the purpose of the `DropDownHeight` property and what is changing the apparent drop down area of the `ComboBox`?

Comment: The IntegralHeight property comes into play sometimes, too.  For the most part though, most designers want to increase the height of the drop down to just show more choices by default.  I'm unsure what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: When I populate then clear the items in the comboBox and click the drop down menu I see 5 blank spaces in the dropdown menu.  I want to know if there is an easy way to type in something like 
    comboBox1.dropDownHeight = value
to adjust the viewable range of the drop down menu.

Comment: Try setting the IntegralHeight to false.

Comment: Perfect.  This accomplishes exactly what I was trying to achieve.  Its still unclear to me why the DropDownHeight value isn't changing when the ComboBox automatically resizes the dropdown area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also not really sure what problem you're trying to solve, but if you're trying to adjust the height of the DropDownHeight, this can be achieved below.

```
private void UpdateDropDownHeight()
{
    int dropDownHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        dropDownHeight = dropDownHeight + (comboBox1.ItemHeight);
    }
    comboBox1.DropDownHeight = dropDownHeight;
    textBox1.Text = comboBox1.DropDownHeight.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you.  This fixes my problem.  It appears the DropDownHeight property only changes when it is set from my code.

Comment: I don't get your code. Why should you add item height in the loop? I am asking this because if there were a scenario where Items.Count would be more than 2 then each iteration ItemsHeight is added to dropDownHeight.

Comment: I use comboBox1.ItemHeight * comboBox1.Items.Count instead of loop. But comboBox1.DropDownHeight doesn't change the height on-the-fly. Only change when opening the dropdown only.